# how to divide screen in a ration using flex box

Tags: react-native, flexbox

If you have a screen of width 100% and you have to divide it in the ratio of 40%:30%:30%, how you will use flex property to achieve such type of division?
Is it correct if I use flex value as 2:1:1 respectively for this division? will it be the exact division ration for 40:30:30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a proportion. Like 3:4:3 which means the total is 10 out of which 3rd part will be assigned to the first and last item and 4th part will be assigned to the second part. So ultimately it will be 30:40:30. Take a look at the below example.

If you will use 2:1:1, the total is 4 which means 100/4 is 25. So it will eventually become 50:25:25. I hope this explanation is clear to you. Let me know if you have any further queries.

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}

.item {
  background: #333;
  height: 4rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.item3 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.item4 {
  flex-grow: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the total of the ratio is changed like in question I used 100% but what if I want 75% width of the screen and then use that 40:30:30 ratio?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can change the width of container to 75% from 100% and the items will share the same ratio 40:30:30. The container will be using 75% of the screen. For items, the container will be the parent and 100% will be respective to that container not to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

If you really wanted it to be, 40%,30% and 30% .

Then use flex:4,flex:3 and flex:3 .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.divs {
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div3 {
 flex:3;
}
.div4 {
 flex:4;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="div4 divs">4</div>
  <div class="div3 divs">3</div>
  <div class="div3 divs">3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if the total of the ratio is changed like in question I used 100% but what if I want 75% width of the screen and then use that 40:30:30 ratio?

Comment: well, you can add "width:75%" to "flex-container", and the rest of the code still the same.